# How to display results

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using PDO whilst following the MVC pattern and I am trying to create multiple divs depending on how many rows are retrieved when a user searches for a car. My query works perfectly however when a user submits the form it does not retrieve any results, does any one understand what I am doing wrong. Here is some of my code so far:

CarData.php class:

```
 public function SearchCar($query2){

    $query = "SELECT make, model, type, colour, price, year, picture
              FROM AllCars car
              JOIN AllMakes mak ON mak.id = car.makeID
              JOIN AllModels model ON model.id = car.modelID
              JOIN AllType typ ON typ.id = car.typeID
              JOIN AllColour col ON col.id = car.colourID";

    $query .= $query2;

    // This is where you need to start setting up the query to run it so you prepare it by putting it in a variable
    $statement = $this->_dbHandle->prepare($query);


    // Then execute the query
    $statement->execute();

    // This will return the row from the database as an array


    $dataSet = [];
    while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $dataSet[] = new CarData2($row);
    }
    return $dataSet;



}
```

The $query2 in the paramaters is what the query depends on as in the buying.php I have:

```
if(isset($_POST["SearchCar"]))
{
if($_POST["MakeOfCar"] == 1){

    $query2 = " WHERE car.makeID > 1";

}
else
{
    $query2 = " WHERE car.makeID = ".$_POST['MakeOfCar'];
}

$SearchCar = $CarData->SearchCar($query2);


}
```

Now when the query is retrieved another class called CarData2.php is what retrieves each row, for example the make and model of the car etc:

```
protected $make, $model, $type, $colour, $price, $year,$picture;

public function __construct($row) {
    $this->make = $row['make'];
    $this->model = $row['model'];
    $this->type = $row['type'];
    $this->colour = $row['colour'];
    $this->price = $row['price'];
    $this->year = $row['year'];
    $this->picture = $row['picture'];
}

public function getMake() {
    return $this->make;
}

public function getModel() {
    return $this->model;
}

public function getType() {
    return $this->type;
}

public function getColour() {
    return $this->colour;
}

public function getPrice() {
    return $this->price;
}

public function getYear() {
    return $this->year;
}

public function getPicture(){
    return $this->picture;
}
```

And this is where I am displaying the results in the buying.phtml:

```
<?php if(isset($view->CarData2))
 {
   if (count($view->CarData2) > 0){
        foreach($view->CarData2 as $ResultCarData) {
          echo '<div class="row">';
          echo '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">';
          echo '<div class="thumbnail">';
          echo '<img src="" alt=""/>';
          echo '<div class="caption">';
          echo '<h2></h2>';
          echo '<h4 class="colouredTitle">Make: </h4>';
          echo  '<h4>' .$ResultCarData->getMake(). '</h4>';
          echo '<h4 class="colouredTitle">Model: </h4>';
          echo  '<h4>' .$ResultCarData->getModel(). '</h4>';
          echo '<h4 class="colouredTitle">Type: </h4>';
          echo  '<h4>' .$ResultCarData->getType(). '</h4>';
          echo '<h4 class="colouredTitle">Colour: </h4>';
          echo  '<h4>' .$ResultCarData->getColour(). '</h4>';
          echo '<h4 class="colouredTitle">Year: </h4>';
          echo  '<h4>' .$ResultCarData->getYear(). '</h4>';
          echo '<h4 class="colouredTitle">Price: </h4>';
          echo  '<h4>' .$ResultCarData->getPrice(). '</h4>';
          echo '</div>';
          echo '</div>';
          echo '</div>';
          echo '</div>';
        }
      }
        else
      {
        echo 'No results found';
      }
  };
?>
```

As you can see im trying to display the results in the DIV and loop it so depending on how many rows are retrieved it creates that many divs to display the results. However it's not displaying anything and I dont know what I have done wrong, does anyone understand what I have done wrong?

Comment: You just append `$query2` at the end to `$query`? There must be sql syntax error.

Comment: Where are you setting the value of $view->CarData2?

Comment: @cybersoft Their is no problem with the SQL procedure as it worked before using a different layout, however i wasnt happy with the layout and decided to use MVC to clean it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this line I think it's in your controller:

```
  $SearchCar = $CarData->SearchCar($query2);
```

And in your view you are trying to get the value of `$view->CarData2`

Then I think you need to set `CarData2` value in your controller, I don't know what is your structure but it could be something like this:

```
  $view->CarData2 = $CarData->SearchCar($query2);
```